# How to save Tbs of Photoshop Files efficiently in my file server?

Tags: filesystems, pictures

I have a File Server with 1Tb of PSD(photoshop) files.

We are a printing company and this psd are directly being used by online editor panel.

I am try to compress these psd but I can't zip/tar them since then everytime it has to be decompressed before it can be opened in the panel.

As per my understanding, there must be something common to all psds, (the basic part of all photoshop files), so I was wondering if somehow I can extract the common part of those files into one file reducing space requirement to an extent.

I tried but could not do it since file were in binaries. How to do this?

Please note, I wasn't sure which community of stackexchange would be best for asking such questions, I felt most confident with serverfault, but in case there is a better community of this question, please help me shifting this question there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is a little unclear, but I think it's probably safe to say that you're looking for some kind of "magic" to either deduplicate or compress Photoshop (PSD) data files.

No such magic exists. There may be very small incremental gains to be made with compression but nothing significant. PSD files (modern versions, that is) already employ compression, resulting in a high entropy density. You can't just compress an already-compressed file and somehow make it smaller. (If you somehow figure out how to do that you'll become insanely rich...)

Deduplication might be possible if your files are sufficiently similar, but it seems highly unlikely that your files are going to be of sufficiently similar composition for you to make any gains that way. There will probably be header / metadata blocks that are similar, but I tend to doubt they'll be any significant size.

TL;DR - What you're asking for is comp-sci "magic" that doesn't exist.

Comment: It should also be noted that with Deduplication, there are very few ways to get it right and about a million ways to get it wrong. So for the OP, if you do choose this route, please do your due diligence before diving in.